# Employee details not displaying properly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Hi this is the database structure.

```
employee (employee-name, street, city)
works (employee-name, company-name, salary)
company (company-name, city)
manages (employee-name, manager-name)
```

I need to get the following details but according to my trainer it is wrong can any0ne tell me what is wrong in the following queries?

Find the names, street addresses, and cities of residence of all employees
who work for First Bank Corporation and earn more than $10,000.

```
SELECT e.employee-name, e.city
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works w
ON e.employee-name = w.employee-name
AND w.company-name = “First Bank Corporation”
GROUP BY e.employee-name
HAVING w.salary > 10000
```

Find all employees in the database who live in the same cities as the companies
for which they work.

```
SELECT e.employee-name
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works w
ON e.employee-name = w.emploee-name
INNER JOIN company c
ON w.company-name = c.company-name
GROUP BY e.employee-name
HAVING e.city = c.city
```

Find all employees in the database who live in the same cities and on the
same streets as do their managers.

```
SELECT employee-name, street, city
FROM employee
INTERSECT
SELECT e.employee-name, e.street, e.city
FROM employee e, manages m
WHERE e.employee-name = m.manager-name
```

Comment: +1 to every 1 who voted me...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid syntax errors on the statement, wrap the column name that contains non literal characters (*like minus sign, spaces,...*) with backtick.

First Query,

```
SELECT  e.`employee-name`, e.city
FROM    employee e
        INNER JOIN works w
            ON e.employee-name = w.employee-name
WHERE   w.`company-name` = 'First Bank Corporation' AND
        w.salary > 10000
```

Second,

```
SELECT  e.`employee-name`
FROM    employee e
        INNER JOIN works w
            ON e.`employee-name` = w.`employee-name`
        INNER JOIN company c
            ON w.`company-name` = c.`company-name`
WHERE   e.city = c.city
```

Third,

```
SELECT  emp.*
FROM    Manages a
        INNER JOIN employee man
            ON a.`manager-name` = man.`employee-name`
        INNER JOIN employee emp
            ON a.`employee-name` = emp.`employee-name`
WHERE   man.city = emp.city AND
        emp.street = man.street
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WHERE` clauses.

Find the names, street addresses, and cities of residence of all employees who work for First Bank Corporation and earn more than $10,000.

```
SELECT e.`employee-name`, e.street, e.city
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works w ON e.`employee-name` = w.`employee-name`
WHERE w.company-name = "First Bank Corporation"
AND w.salary > 10000
```

Use WHERE clauses and not `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Find all employees in the database who live in the same cities as the companies for which they work.

```
SELECT e.`employee-name`
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works w ON e.`employee-name` = w.`employee-name`
INNER JOIN company c ON w.`company-name` = c.`company-name`
WHERE e.city = c.city
```

Find all employees in the database who live in the same cities and on the same streets as do their managers.

```
SELECT m.`employee-name`
FROM manages m
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.`employee-name` = m.`employee-name`
INNER JOIN employee manager ON manager.`employee-name` = m.`manager-name`
WHERE e.street = manager.street
AND e.city = manager.city
```

Comment: I almost downvoted you because all of your answers causes syntax error. you haven't delimited the column names which contains `-`. Mysql performs arithmetic operation on the column. `e.employee-name` = `e.employee minus name`, if those columns are not found on the table, the server wil thrown unknown column name.

Comment: On your last query, it should be `m.street` not `manager.street`.

Comment: Ok for the `-` part, it's indeed a mistake if it works the way you tell. About the `m.street`, `m` is the `manages` table, it contains only `manager-name` and `employee-name`. `manager.street` sounds the right thing to do.

Comment: @JW Edited my answer to take into account your remark about `-` :)

Comment: @JW +1 for your better answer to the question, and for having teached me about mySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the first 2 by using WHERE instead of GROUP BY and HAVING. 
First one:

```
SELECT e.employee-name, e.city
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works w
ON e.employee-name = w.employee-name
WHERE w.company-name = “First Bank Corporation”
AND w.salary > 10000
```

Second one:

```
SELECT e.employee-name
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works w
ON e.employee-name = w.employee-name
INNER JOIN company c
ON w.company-name = c.company-name
WHERE e.city = c.city
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd solve the first one:

```
SELECT employee-name, street, city 
FROM employee 
WHERE employee-name = (
SELECT employee-name 
FROM works where company-name = "First Bank Corporation" 
AND salary > 10000)
```

If you need help with the rest just tell me

Comment: That is pretty inefficient - better doing the inner join

Comment: True, I've just always disliked using the JOIN keyword :p

Comment: It's there for a very basic reason and this is it!